Questions about the definition of generalized Lelong number by Demailly
According to Demailly, the definition of Lelong number is local, so assume $X$ is a Stein manifold, $\varphi$ is a continuous psh function (which means $e^{\varphi}$ is continuous. Let $T$ be a closed positive current of bidimension $(p,p)$, then

If $\varphi$ is semi-exhaustative on $\operatorname{Supp} T$, which means there exists $R$ such that $B(R)\cap \operatorname{Supp} T\subset \subset X$, then for any $r\in (-\infty,R)$, set
$$
\nu(T,\varphi,r)=\int_{\{\varphi<r\}}T\wedge (dd^c\varphi)^p,
$$
and the Lelong number $\nu(T,\varphi)$ is defined as
$$
\nu(T,\varphi)=\lim_{r\to -\infty}\nu(T,\varphi,r).
$$

To verify it's well-defined, for any $p\geq 1$ we know the measure $T\wedge (dd^c\varphi)^p$ is a well-defined measure by Proposition 4.1 and Corollary 4.3 as follows:

Proposition. We make two additional assumptions:
a) $T$ has non zero bidimension $(p, p)$ (i.e. degree of $T<2 n$ ).
b) $X$ is covered by a family of Stein open sets $\Omega \subset
> \subset X$ whose boundaries $\partial \Omega$ do not intersect $L(u)
> \cap$ Supp $T$.
Then the current uT has locally finite mass in $X$.

and

Corollary. Let $u_1, \ldots, u_q$ be plurisubharmonic functions on $X$ such that $X$ is covered by Stein open sets $\Omega$ with
$\partial \Omega \cap L\left(u_j\right) \cap \operatorname{Supp}
> T=\emptyset$. We use again induction to define $$ d d^c u_1 \wedge d
>      d^c u_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge d d^c u_q \wedge T=d d^c\left(u_1 d d^c
>      u_2 \ldots \wedge d d^c u_q \wedge T\right) $$

Also, we have the following proposition:

Proposition. Let $\Omega \subset \subset X$ be a Stein open subset. If $V$ is a plurisubharmonic function on $X$ and $u_1, \ldots,
> u_q, 1 \leqslant q \leqslant n-1$, are plurisubharmonic functions such
that $\partial \Omega \cap L\left(u_j\right)=\emptyset$, then $V d d^c
> u_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge d d^c u_q$ has locally finite mass in
$\Omega$.

However, for $p=0$, i.e. $T$ is a measure, I can't find anything in Demailly's book to check the definition is well-defined. But I think the proposition above still holds for $q=n$: just consider $\Omega\times \mathbb{C}\subset X\times \mathbb{C}$ and $u_1,\cdots,u_n$ are psh function depending only on the first factor.
Then we can use the proposition above to check the definition is well-defined for $p=0$. Is my proof correct?
